Finding division points of Heegner point using SAGE
Let $E$ be an elliptic curve defined over $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $K$ be an imaginary quadratic field satisfying the Heegner hypothesis and $P$ a Heegner point in $E(K)$. Let $p$ be a prime and consider all points $S$ in $E(\bar{\mathbb{Q}})$ (where $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$) satisfying $pS=P$. For each such point I would like to calculate the degree of the extension $K(S)/K$ ($K(S)$ is the field constructed by adjoining the coordinates of $S$).
I'm not sure how to do this in Sage. Let $E=11A1$,
$K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7})$ and $p=3$.
E = EllipticCurve("11a1")
P = E.heegner_point(-7)
Pt = P.point_exact()

If I try Pt.division_points(3), I get nothing because this only finds the division points in the rationals.
So we need to first do E2 = E.base_extend(QQbar) and then consider the point Pt on E2 and then use division_points(3).
How do get a point Pt on E2? If I try E2(Pt.xy()), I get an error saying
ValueError: need a real or complex embedding to convert 
            a non rational element of a number field into an algebraic number

I'm not sure how to do my desired computation. Any help with this would be highly appreciated.

I'm not sure why this question was closed. Coding questions are on-topic, the OP's question is clear, and they have shown their work. That being said: this question may be more likely to get an answer on MathOverflow.

Please format the code in your question as code (using backticks for inline and triple backticks or indentation for code blocks).

I think the fastest way to get an answer to this is to ask the sage-support mailing list. This feels doable; but I sat and fiddled around for a few minutes to see if I could get it to work and failed.

I am trying to drop an answer...

Here is the way i would try to proceed in the given special situation. Usually, combining sage computation with the mathematical intuition should give a result, sage alone cannot solve all structural problems we have.
Let us initialize the given situation, and see which is that exact Heegner point.
E = EllipticCurve("11a1")
P = E.heegner_point(-7).point_exact()

Then the point P is:
sage: P
(a : -4*a + 3 : 1)

And what is a in there? We look at the first component and/or base ring of Pt.
sage: P.base_ring()
Number Field in a with defining polynomial x^2 - x + 2
sage: P[0]
a
sage: P[0].parent()
Number Field in a with defining polynomial x^2 - x + 2

We can isolate this ring / field and use it.
K = P.base_ring()
K.inject_variables()

The last inject is Defining a.
Now let us search for points $S$ in a further extension with $3S=P$. For this, it is simplest to work over $\Bbb Q$. I will denote by EE the curve E, seen over this new base field.
R0.<x> = PolynomialRing(QQ)
R.<X> = PolynomialRing(QQbar)
A = QQbar(sqrt(-7))

g = ( E.multiplication_by_m(3)[0] - A ).numerator()
h = ( E.multiplication_by_m(3)[0] + A ).numerator()

f = g*h       # in QQ[x], Galois invariant w.r.t. A --> -A
f0 = R0(f)    # its version with parent over QQ, not needed, but better printed

And we have the following polynomial in our hands:
sage: latex(f0)

$$
\small
x^{18} + 807 x^{16} + 608 x^{15} - 27444 x^{14} + 421236 x^{13} + 4825858 x^{12} + 179808 x^{11} - 40600032 x^{10} - 216159042 x^{9} - 851581170 x^{8} + 112723188 x^{7} + 10283936729 x^{6} + 28513105656 x^{5} + 37842699825 x^{4} + 66528730714 x^{3} + 206518248267 x^{2} + 322498951590 x + 211471661248
$$
Let $x_0$ be one root of this polynomial. Can we lift it to a point on $E(\Bbb Q)$. Let us see:
EE = E.base_extend(QQbar)
for x0 in f0.roots(ring=QQbar, multiplicities=False):
    S0 = EE.lift_x(x0)
    y0 = S0[1]
    print(f"POINT (x0, y0) = {S0.xy()}")
    print(f"       x0 has minimal polynomial: {x0.minpoly()}")
    print(f"       y0 has minimal polynomial: {y0.minpoly()}")

We obtain a long list, for each x0 we have y0 in a bigger field. All the above $x_0$-values have the same minimal polynomial (over the rationals)
of degree eighteen, the above polynomial. The degree gets doubled in all cases to get a corresponding $y_0$-value in each case. The minimal polynomial of each such $y_0$
is
sage: latex(y0.minpoly())

$$
\small
x^{36} + 18 x^{35} + 723 x^{34} + 10506 x^{33} + 620020818 x^{32} + 9919439976 x^{31} + 1256243959406 x^{30} + 18074916427494 x^{29} + 1116174886487679 x^{28} + 14413782642266508 x^{27} + 499313189204805897 x^{26} + 5662001198294929566 x^{25} + 184626582379955769964 x^{24} + 1940649172506922826208 x^{23} + 31863804732577559311479 x^{22} + 270959588852166205728340 x^{21} + 3555158056859988818853378 x^{20} + 26617974717400903714070178 x^{19} + 288025865398095568597791457 x^{18} + 1883207748451804221314030742 x^{17} + 16192312560312046259553100644 x^{16} + 89971798018241035470418517704 x^{15} + 607042023763996176087012112263 x^{14} + 2808670480985186359890517057560 x^{13} + 14884569007662605337306246347938 x^{12} + 56393953093786227336473391126978 x^{11} + 231859152760579633706157077697753 x^{10} + 699927665849090249178886654271958 x^{9} + 2164726093136867953473332339388666 x^{8} + 4981747923734440492304235667300482 x^{7} + 10699901310732792518483739527012320 x^{6} + 17085596464235302808268827366038416 x^{5} + 22108255960322981385289552397041959 x^{4} + 20411046539626851055601179776466832 x^{3} + 35447636641270826336559998170552113 x^{2} + 27430274154264003784025740489744992 x + 236730139315273247699861969984767088
$$
We want only the degree, which is $36$.

One more check (with the last value for S0):
sage: (3*S0)[0].minpoly()
x^2 + 7


Making now the long story short:
p = 3
D = -7

E = EllipticCurve("11a1")
P = E.heegner_point(D).point_exact()
A = QQbar(sqrt(D))

g = ( E.multiplication_by_m(p)[0] - A ).numerator()
h = ( E.multiplication_by_m(p)[0] + A ).numerator() 
f = g*h

R0.<x> = PolynomialRing(QQ)
f0 = R0(f)
EE = E.base_extend(QQbar)

for x0 in f0.roots(ring=QQbar, multiplicities=False):
    S0 = EE.lift_x(x0)
    y0 = S0[1]
    print(f"POINT (x0, y0) = {S0.xy()}")
    print(f"       x0 has minimal polynomial of degree: {x0.minpoly().degree()}")
    print(f"       y0 has minimal polynomial of degree: {y0.minpoly().degree()}")


That line with A = QQbar(sqrt(D)) initializes A to be the first component in P. In other cases please adjust to fit. (Or code to have the general situation covered.)
